# SQL Foreign Keys/Relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, foreign-key-relationship

Having briefly studied databases in college, I haven't worked with them since and have drawn a bit of a blank, so I was wondering if someone could help me out. I have a database called Convert, which holds the following tables:

```
**File**
ID  int  PK
ISBN nvarchar(MAX)
UserName nvarchar(50)
CoverID
PDFID

**PDF**
PDFID int PK
FileContent image
MimeType nvarchar
FileName nvarchar

**Cover**
CoverID int PK
FileContent image
MimeType nvarchar
FileName nvarchar
```

I've just drawn a blank on two things really.

1. Relationships. I *think* if I a sql query such as below I will create foreign keys:

   Alter TABLE Cover ADD FOREIGN KEY (CoverID) REFERENCES File (CoverID)

What I need to do is create one to one relationships --> One File will have one Cover, and one PDF.

The second is thing I'm having difficulty getting my head around again is the insert statements. Any advice on how I should handle those would be appreciated?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Also.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Apologies if it was not clear. I'm having difficulty on remembering how I would create a one to one relationship between my tables, and following that, how I would handle insert statements to these tables.

Comment: BTW nvarchar (max) should not be used indiscriminately but only if you are planning to have over 4000 characters. It can cause performance problems if you use it for things like ISBN which will never approach that. Take the time to figure out how large a field should be and don;t rely on using nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to ensure that a relation will have one to one relationship, then make one big table.

one table where you have

```
create table

ID  int  PK

ISBN nvarchar(MAX)

UserName nvarchar(50)


PDFFileContent image

PDFFileName nvarchar

CoverFileContent image

CoverFileName nvarchar
```

what you might ment in your original design is to make one table that could contain all 3 types and each row is different by having different value at "mime type" which is also possible, if hold keys that relet the table to itself.

such as

```
create table
ID int pk
ISBN nvarchar(max)
userName nvarchar(50)
pdfID int fk table2 id
coverID int fk table 2 id

create table2
id pk int
fileContent image
fileName nvarchar
mimetype (something)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to retain your current table structure (and @none is right - if it's really a one-to-one relationship there's no benefit to having three tables) you can get what you want by doing the following:

1. Define two foreign key constraints on File, one on File.PDFID referencing PDF.PDFID and the other on File.CoverID referencing Cover.CoverID.
2. Define two UNIQUE constraints on the File table, one on File.PDFID and the other on File.CoverID.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

A true one-to-one relationship would look like:

[image]

which is essentially a vertically partitioned table. In this case, you may also consider simply putting all columns in one table.